# Openmp critical section inside if conditional statement

Tags: parallel-computing

I have a function like this

```
void foo(x, *y) {
    some calculations

    if (x > *y) {
        *y = x/2;
    }

    more calculations
}
```

My parallel section is

```
int x[] = some array;
double y=0;
#pragma omp parallel for
for ( int i  = 0; i<=n; i++) {
    do something 
    for ( int j = 0; j<=n; j++) {
           foo(x[i], &y);
}
```

If I rewrite the if statement as

```
*y = x > *y ? x/2 : *y;
```

I can do

```
#pragma omp critical
*y = x > *y ? x/2 : *y;
```

But I don’t want to change the code. How do I create a critical section for the conditional
y-update block?

Comment: Can you use `#pragma omp atomic write` ? This would avoid the critical section, which would probably need to include the full if block.

Comment: Where is your parallel section? Doing critical only means if you have a team of threads.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I re-edited my question, can you help take a look? Thank you so much!

Comment: What's wrong with putting a critical after the "if" test?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Is this going to be a race condition because it can happen that every thread is reading *y and then all pass the test before writing can happen?

Comment: I see your point. Ok, this is really a max reduction on the values x[i] (modified or original), so why don't you write it as a reduction? Then all coherence stuff is taken care of for you.

Comment: Critical applies to a structured block, not just a single line (see e.g. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/openmp/reference/openmp-directives?view=vs-2019#critical) - why not just stick curly braces round the critical bit?

Comment: @IanBush This is just what I want, thank you!!

Comment: Can you also take a look at my question here (https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/35780/openmp-critical) regarding the linked example mentioned above?